# Установил Visual Studio 10. При компиляции файлов C++ выдает ошибку LINK1123 Сбой при преобразовании в COFF. Файл недопустим или поврежден

Tags: visual-c++

Установил Visual Studio 10. При компиляции файлов C++ выдает ошибку LINK1123 Сбой при преобразовании в COFF. Файл недопустим или поврежден. Поставил C++  с экспресс студии - та же проблема, хотя до установки полной версии экспресс работала.

Comment: обязательно нужна VS 2010? на днях вышла VS 2015 Update 1 -- Сommunity версия бесплатная.

Comment: AVAST установлен?